# why is computeBoundingBox() working differently if switching to another browser tab during loading?

Tags: three.js, bounding-box

I’m working on a complex project in threejs.
Trying to cut the corner:
I have to load an obj, create some pivot point to use as parent of the mesh inside this obj, let the user move and rotate the pivots.
It takes somewhere about 10 to 15 seconds to load due to its complexity.
My problem is that it is working flawlessly if I load the page and don’t change the focus, but if I change the browser tab or collapse the browser window I got a very specific problem:

`geometry.computeBoundingBox()` gives different results.

Is there someone who can help me figure out what’s happening?

To help you better understand the situation: at loading time I have to rotate the obj to -90° on the X axis (inverting Y and Z as a consequence); I think it’s relevant because the boundingBox calculation somehow inverts Y and Z and changes its min and max also, but as I said only if I switch tab or collapse the browser.

p.s. No matter the OS nor the browser. It’s a super consistent bug

Comment: Please provide a working example so others can see the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks Marquizzo, I will try to build something to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I somehow solved the issue, but take it with a grain of salt:

the problem can be tracked back to the execution stack of javascript:
the first function computes the bounding box, the second uses this computation, but if the first function is somehow slower to execute, the second could not have what it needs.

What I did is to force javascript to execute functions in a given order and only when the previous is finished.

The problem occurred only when changing the tab because browsers optimize resources of non visible tabs, but the code I wrote was anyway too much entropic to work properly.

I hope what I found will be understandable and useful to someone else in future.